# MongoDB - SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression in $regex

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor

I use $regex to find a record in mongodb collection. Basically, I use it as a search to return all records that match a "query" partially or entirely. It works just fine until I have characters like [, (, ", etc. All the options to escape brake results and I get 0 records back.

I tried packages similar to escape-regexp but strings that get produced brake results and don't match with database records.

```
const query = "MacBook Pro ("
const objectName = "laptops"

return Inventory.find({
    $and: [
        { 'type': objectName},
        { 'specs': {$elemMatch: {'specValueLabel': {$regex: ".*" + query + ".*", $options: "i"} }}}
    ] });

// returns the following error: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /.*macbook pro (.*/: Unterminated group
```

Comment: I have used lodash's escape regexp successfully: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.escaperegexp

Answer (score 2):

You can install lodash with `meteor npm install lodash`

You don't need to use atmosphere packages any more unless there is no choice.

The problem is that you are doing `/.*MacBook Pro (./` which is saying to Javascript that it is already a regular expression. The `(` character is the start of a capture group.

So pass the string in as just a quoted string for escaping, eg `_.escapeRegExp(".*MacBook Pro (.*")`

You can try this out by going to www.lodash.com and opening the Chrome dev tools (Lodash is loaded on this site), and type in to the console:

`_.escapeRegExp(".*MacBook Pro (.*")
-> "\.\*MacBook Pro \(\.\*"`

This will fix it for you